# how store the dynamically generated image views in onsaved instance state android

Tags: android

I am generating image views dynamically based on the arraylist size in button click event, now i change the orientation of the device the views are not visible,

Please help me how to hold the dynamically generated view in onsaved instance state and how to retrieve them in onrestoreinstance state.
Any suggestion will be helpfull.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See this

http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/03/save-and-restore-instance-state.html

Now u need to save image resources to bundle

```
    bundle.putInt("IMG", R.id.image);
```

If there are many images use

```
bundle.putIntArray(key, value);
```

and to get images use

```
    bundle.getInt("IMG");
```

or

```
bundle.getIntArray("IMG");
```